# When finding the radius of convergence of a series, why do you have to didferentiate the series to check the endpoints?

Tags: calculus

Say you have a series that you want to find the radius of convergence of.  You apply the ratio test definition and get that $a < x < b$, and now you have to check the endpoints $a$ and $b$.  Can someone explain to me why we have to plug these into the derivative of the series and not the series itself?  Aren't we trying to see whether the original series (and not its derivative) converges at those points?

Comment: I don't know from where you take that the series must be differentiated to find out what happens at the end points of the interval of convergence...

Comment: During a GRE review session my professor did this and when I asked him why he told me "its part of the theory", yet my calculus book doesn't say this.

Comment: I never heard of such a thing... Maybe that was a very particular case and he did something wider? In fact, differentiating a power series can make us lose end points.

Comment: I will try to find the problem and post it.

Comment: Ok, it will be interesting to see.

Comment: Perhaps you had some series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and you had to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$ to show that it was greater than $1$ ? 

And then perhaps the way to find this particular limit was to differentiate it i.e. Le Hospital's Rule ?

Comment: I think you want to check if the function is analytic at the end points. Can you write the precise series of function ?